# Importing certificate to a keyring

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, pem

Using a new utility kyrtool, I've been trying to create keyring and import the particular domain certificate into it.

Certificate has been issued by RapidSSL. It's an SHA2 certificate issued for "*.domain.tld".

First of all I've created a new keyring file:

```
kyrtool create -k C:\path\keyring.kyr -p password
```

Then I've converted my pfx certificate to pem in opnessl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.pem
```

Then I've tried to import my PEM into the new keyring:

```
kyrtool import all -i certificate.pem -k C:\path\keyring.kyr -v
```

And an error occured:

```
Using keyring path 'C:\path\keyring.kyr'
No private key found in the input file
ReadPEMPrivateKey returned error 0x0495
Invalid arguments
```

My PEM certificate contains both -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- blocks.

Any idea?
Thanks, JiKra

Comment: I suggest to first check your input file using the "verify" command: `kyrtool verify certificate.pem`. That will most probably tell you, what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem was with the wrong order in certificate chain in PEM file. There was a global CA (GeoTrust CA) certificate before the issuer certificate (RapidSSL 256 - G3).

We've resolved the problem by dividing the whole certificate into four separate PEM files and importing them in the proper order.

```
kyrtool import keys
kyrtool import certs
kyrtool import roots ...global
kyrtool import roots ...intemediate
```

JiKra

EDIT 1:

As we realized, the main problem could be with the intermediate certificate of RapidSSL 256 G3 where there were no paddings at the end. This certificate ends exactly with 7bit content:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: That was, what I meant with "verify": That command would have told you, that the issuers do not match / the order was wrong...

Comment: Yes, but first of all I had to check what AVA separator means. :-)